# How does this code create an instance of a class which has only a private constructor? 

Tags: c++, private-constructor

I'm working on a sound library (with OpenAL), and taking inspiration from the interface provided by FMOD, you can see the interface [at this link](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid93295E740BB8C893F7E1F2E6DC72857E25828DC2.aspx).

I've provided some concepts like: Sound, Channel and ChannelGroup, as you can see through FMOD interface, all of those classes have a private constructor and, for example, if you would create a Sound you mast use the function *createSound()* provided by the System class (the same if you would create a Channel or a ChannelGroup).

I'd like to provide a similar mechanism, but I don't understand how it work behind. For example, how can the function *createSound()* create a new istance of a Sound? The constructor is private and from the Sound interface there aren't any static methods or friendship. Are used some patterns?

**EDIT: Just to make OP's question clear, s/he is not asking how to create a instance of class with private constructor, The question is in the link posted, how is instance of classes created which have private constructor and NO static methods or friend functions.**

Thanks.

Comment: Have tou tried to use friend members

Comment: That interface looks rather poor. In general, "System" or "god" classes are known as an anti-pattern.

Comment: Is it creating an instance of a subclass that does have a public or friend constructor and returning that?

Comment: Do not use that code as a reference for design in C++, that code is a *wrapper* of C code, so it throws some OO sugar on top of a non-OO design, but that is not a good OO design.

Comment: Yes, in fact I need to rethink my interface and not to refer to this.

Answer (score 7):

Hard to say without seeing the source code. Seems however that FMOD is 100% C with global variables and with a bad "OOP" C++ wrapper around it.

Given the absence of source code and a few of the bad tricks that are played in the .h files may be the code is compiled using a different header file and then just happens to work (even if it's clearly non-standard) with the compilers they are using.

My guess is that the real (unpublished) source code for the C++ wrapper is defining a static method or alternatively if everything is indeed just global then the object is not really even created and tricks are being played to fool C++ object system to think there is indeed an object. Apparently all dispatching is static so this (while not formally legal) can happen to work anyway with C++ implementations I know.

Whatever they did it's quite ugly and non-conforming from a C++ point of view.

Comment: +1 for being the only answerer who read the question. And for being right - there is no standard-comliant way to do this.

Comment: It's clear, I think that the better job is rethink my interface.

Answer (score 1):

They never create any instances! The factory function is right there in the header

```
/*
    FMOD System factory functions.
*/
inline FMOD_RESULT System_Create(System **system)
{ return FMOD_System_Create((FMOD_SYSTEM **)system); }
```

The pointer you pass in to get a System object is immediately cast to a pointer to a C struct declared in the fmod.h header.

As it is a class without any data members who can tell the difference?

Comment: You mean they call a C function passing the address to where to store the pointer (but what does this function actually do is not shown). I'm not sure the real C object indeed has no data members because given the level of unportable non-standard trickery being used here I wouldn't be surprised that the library indeed is compiled using different headers and that the visible headers are indeed just for library users.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Foo {
    enum Type {
        ALPHA,
        BETA_X,
        BETA_Y
    };
    Type type () const;
    static Foo alpha (int i) {return Foo (ALPHA, i);}
    static Foo beta  (int i) {return Foo (i<0 ? BETA_X : BETA_Y, i);}
private:
    Foo (Type, int);
};
```

create_alpha could have been a free function declared `friend` but that's just polluting the namespace.

I'm afraid I can't access that link but another way could be a factory pattern. I'm guessing a bit, now.

Comment: There are no `static methods` in those interfaces which OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is the factory pattern - as their comment says.

```
/*
    FMOD System factory functions.
*/
inline FMOD_RESULT System_Create(System **system) { return FMOD_System_Create((FMOD_SYSTEM **)system); }
```

It's difficult to say exactly what is happening as they don't publish the source for the `FMOD_System_Create` method.

The factory pattern is a mechanism for creating an object but the (sub)class produced depends on the parameters of the factory call. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern